# Got error "Waited for xxx due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness" when Kubeflow Training Operator

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I have a local Kubernetes created by Rancher Desktop. I am trying to deploy based on the [installation guide](https://github.com/kubeflow/training-operator#installation).

However, after deploying by

```bash
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/training-operator/manifests/overlays/standalone?ref=v1.6.0"
```

The Kubeflow Training Operator pod is in a CrashLoopBackOff state, with the following log:

```
➜ kubectl logs training-operator-xxx -n kubeflow

I0714 04:54:03.434723       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.024840626s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/packages.operators.coreos.com/v1?timeout=32s
1.689310446978421e+09   INFO    controller-runtime.metrics  Metrics server is starting to listen    {"addr": ":8080"}
I0714 04:54:14.225698       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.047503167s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
I0714 04:54:24.275500       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.948469293s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/artifact.apicur.io/v1alpha1?timeout=32s
I0714 04:54:34.325909       1 request.go:682] Waited for 2.849523377s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/operators.coreos.com/v1?timeout=32s
I0714 04:54:44.724674       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.047644251s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/operators.coreos.com/v1?timeout=32s
I0714 04:54:54.774273       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.947402376s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1?timeout=32s
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Kubeflow Training Operator pod requires an additional startup time on their first initialization.

So we can patch by adding `startupProbe` with higher `failureThreshold`.

Here is the working version:

```bash
kubectl apply --kustomize=kubeflow-training-operator
```

- **kubeflow-training-operator/kustomization.yaml**

  ```yaml
  resources:
    - github.com/kubeflow/training-operator/manifests/overlays/standalone?ref=v1.6.0
  patches:
    - path: training-operator-deployment-patch.yaml
  ```
- **kubeflow-training-operator/training-operator-deployment-patch.yaml**

  ```yaml
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: training-operator
  spec:
    template:
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: training-operator
            startupProbe:
              httpGet:
                path: /healthz
                port: 8081
              failureThreshold: 30
  ```

Then I can see it got deployed properly:

```bash
➜ kubectl logs training-operator-xxx -n kubeflow

I0714 05:41:03.499300       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.041055501s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1?timeout=32s
1.6893132670509896e+09  INFO  controller-runtime.metrics  Metrics server is starting to listen  {"addr": ":8080"}
I0714 05:41:14.295944       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.048299708s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/registry.apicur.io/v1?timeout=32s
I0714 05:41:24.296220       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.898473292s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
I0714 05:41:34.345574       1 request.go:682] Waited for 2.797829418s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s
I0714 05:41:44.795474       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.048790793s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/operators.coreos.com/v1alpha2?timeout=32s
I0714 05:41:54.845438       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.945571376s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1?timeout=32s
I0714 05:42:04.846740       1 request.go:682] Waited for 2.798720251s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/apm.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1?timeout=32s
I0714 05:42:15.295114       1 request.go:682] Waited for 1.047853292s due to client-side throttling, not priority and fairness, request: GET:https://10.43.0.1:443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
1.689313340247459e+09 INFO  setup starting manager
1.6893133402522147e+09  INFO  Starting server {"kind": "health probe", "addr": "[::]:8081"}
1.6893133402523057e+09  INFO  Starting server {"path": "/metrics", "kind": "metrics", "addr": "[::]:8080"}
1.6893133402535763e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "paddlejob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.PaddleJob"}
1.6893133402535298e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mxjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.MXJob"}
1.6893133402539213e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "paddlejob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Pod"}
1.6893133402539287e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mxjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Pod"}
1.6893133402534788e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "tfjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.TFJob"}
1.689313340253958e+09 INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "tfjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Pod"}
1.6893133402535348e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "pytorchjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.PyTorchJob"}
1.6893133402540202e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "pytorchjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Pod"}
1.6893133402534842e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "xgboostjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.XGBoostJob"}
1.6893133402540386e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "xgboostjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Pod"}
1.6893133402540817e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "pytorchjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Service"}
1.6893133402540936e+09  INFO  Starting Controller {"controller": "pytorchjob-controller"}
1.6893133402541058e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "tfjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Service"}
1.689313340254115e+09 INFO  Starting Controller {"controller": "tfjob-controller"}
1.6893133402534952e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.MPIJob"}
1.6893133402541409e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Pod"}
1.6893133402541444e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.ConfigMap"}
1.6893133402542117e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mxjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Service"}
1.6893133402542229e+09  INFO  Starting Controller {"controller": "mxjob-controller"}
1.6893133402542326e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "paddlejob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Service"}
1.6893133402542348e+09  INFO  Starting Controller {"controller": "paddlejob-controller"}
1.6893133402542171e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Role"}
1.6893133402542467e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.RoleBinding"}
1.6893133402542505e+09  INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.ServiceAccount"}
1.6893133402542531e+09  INFO  Starting Controller {"controller": "mpijob-controller"}
1.689313340254083e+09 INFO  Starting EventSource  {"controller": "xgboostjob-controller", "source": "kind source: *v1.Service"}
1.6893133402546306e+09  INFO  Starting Controller {"controller": "xgboostjob-controller"}
1.6893133403579748e+09  INFO  Starting workers  {"controller": "paddlejob-controller", "worker count": 1}
1.6893133403599951e+09  INFO  Starting workers  {"controller": "xgboostjob-controller", "worker count": 1}
1.6893133403601058e+09  INFO  Starting workers  {"controller": "pytorchjob-controller", "worker count": 1}
1.6893133403601074e+09  INFO  Starting workers  {"controller": "mxjob-controller", "worker count": 1}
1.6893133403601336e+09  INFO  Starting workers  {"controller": "tfjob-controller", "worker count": 1}
1.6893133403601432e+09  INFO  Starting workers  {"controller": "mpijob-controller", "worker count": 1}
```

References:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/
- https://github.com/kubeflow/training-operator/issues/1841#issuecomment-1611139934
- https://github.com/kubeflow/training-operator/issues/1841#issuecomment-1611156548